# multiple operations on combinations of columns in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations, series

using the following commands I built a sample data frame with named series, Then I made another frame with all possible pairs of column names.

```
dataset <- data.frame(randwalk(10), randwalk(10), randwalk(10), randwalk(10), randwalk(10))
colnames(dataset) <- c( "one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
datasetpairs = data.frame(t(combn(colnames(dataset), 2)))
colnames(datasetpairs) <- c("numerator", "denominator")
```

they look like this:

```
head(dataset)
        one       two    three     four     five
1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
2 1.0055678 0.9866026 1.004089 1.007859 1.004886
3 1.0137884 0.9794308 1.013057 1.011453 1.003129
4 1.0043928 0.9838919 1.026479 1.025951 1.005845
5 0.9942291 0.9839125 1.026769 1.030824 1.007177
6 0.9993814 0.9618307 1.035784 1.037156 1.026317
head(datasetpairs)
  numerator denominator
1       one         two
2       one       three
3       one        four
4       one        five
5       two       three
6       two        four
```

What I want to do is add several columns to "datasetpairs", to store the average, max, and min of the ratio of each column pair. 
I can get a single figure by piping the values in from each row, so I could do a FOR loop, but I was trying to do it vector style like:

```
datasetpairs$mean <- mean( dataset[[datasetpairs$numerator]] / 
dataset[[datasetpairs$demonimator]]
```

but that gave me an error.
Furthermore, what I really want to do is calculate the ratio from the two columns only once, and store several values from analyses before moving on to the next without storing it, as in reality my dataset is too large to calculate all the possible combinations of ratios beforehand.  What's an elegant way to do this without resorting to loops?
Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: I wrote a gist that I think gets at what you're looking for: https://gist.github.com/brshallo/5091536745b9a7ab596b5c9fe6b9922a

Comment: @BryanShalloway Interesting.  It's been a while since I was on this project but I'll make a note for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you using data.table (as it's fast with many grouped operations) and a custom function to do your analysis. That way, your code is readable and you calculate each ratio only once before moving on.

```
library(data.table)

#create data
set.seed(123)
dataset <- data.frame(matrix(runif(50),ncol=5))
colnames(dataset) <- c( "one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

#custom function to process two vectors:
process_data <- function(v1,v2){
  ratio <- v1/v2
  res <- list(mean=mean(ratio),min=min(ratio),max=max(ratio))
  return(res)
}

datasetpairs = data.table(t(combn(colnames(dataset), 2)))
colnames(datasetpairs) <- c("numerator", "denominator")

#run the analysis
datasetpairs[,process_data(dataset[[numerator]],dataset[[denominator]]),by=.(numerator,denominator)]
```

Comment: ignore my (deleted) previous comment.  I missed a couple of lines.  

I get an error with data.table.  I'm looking for the package now...

Comment: got it.  That's awesome.  Thanks a lot!